# Outlook 2010 show which sender's email uses the most space

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange

A customer asked me this question, it seems her mailbox is full (running Exchange SBS2011, Outlook 2010) at 6GB. Instead of asking for more space, she would like to delete the unneeded emails.

Q: Is there any way to sort the emails so that one can see how much space is used by email from specific sender?

Comment: I do not have outlook anymore, but you can sort all mails which are in the same folder by user. Sadly someone smart enough to ask how to do this rather than just ask for more space might actually structure her mail in folders. In that case this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

One possible partially automated method.

First:
Ceate a search folder based on sender.
Can be automated. http://www.slipstick.com/developer/create-an-outlook-search-folder-using-vba/

```
Sub SearchFolderForSender() 
    On Error GoTo Err_SearchFolderForSender 
    Dim strFilter As String
    ' lets get the email address from a selected message 
    Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem 
    Set oMail = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1) 
    strFilter = oMail.SenderEmailAddress 
    If strFilter = "" Then Exit Sub
    Dim strDASLFilter As String
    ' From email address 
    Const From1 As String = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0065001f"
    Const From2 As String = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0042001f"
    strDASLFilter = "(""" & From1 & """ CI_STARTSWITH '" & strFilter & "' OR """ & From2 & """ CI_STARTSWITH '" & strFilter & "')"
    ' From Display name 
    'strDASLFilter = """urn:schemas:httpmail:fromname"" LIKE '" & strFilter & "' " 
    Dim strScope As String
    strScope = "Inbox"
    Dim objSearch As Search 
    Set objSearch = Application.AdvancedSearch(Scope:=strScope, Filter:=strDASLFilter, SearchSubFolders:=True, Tag:="SearchFolder") 
    'Save the search results to a searchfolder 
    objSearch.Save (strFilter) 
    Set objSearch = Nothing
    Exit Sub
Err_SearchFolderForSender: 
    MsgBox "Error # " & Err & " : " & Error(Err) 
End Sub
```

Second: Go to the search folder.

Third: Select all items.

Can be automated.

```
Sub ctrlHomeCtrlEnd()
    SendKeys ("^{HOME}^+{END}")
End Sub
```

Fourth:
Sum the Size property.
http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?47283-Custom-Field-loop-through-each-email-and-add-the-value

```
Sub SizeCount()

' http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?47283-Custom-Field-loop-through-each-email-and-add-the-value

Dim myOlExp As Explorer
Dim myOlSel As Selection

Dim oItem As Object
Dim itemSize As Double
Dim tmpValue As Double
Dim x As Long

Dim uBegin
Dim uDuration
Dim uMsg As String

Set myOlExp = Application.ActiveExplorer
Set myOlSel = myOlExp.Selection
tmpValue = 0
uBegin = Now

'Debug.Print " Start: " & Now

For x = 1 To myOlSel.count

    Set oItem = myOlSel.item(x)
    itemSize = oItem.ItemProperties.item("Size")

    If oItem.ItemProperties.item("Size") = "" Then
        itemSize = 0
    End If

    'Debug.Print "x: " & x & " - " & itemSize; ""

    tmpValue = tmpValue + itemSize

Next x

uDuration = dateDiff("s", uBegin, Now)
Debug.Print " End  : " & Now & "   Total time: " & uDuration & " seconds."

uMsg = "  Total Size of  " & myOlSel.count & "  items: " & Format$(tmpValue / 1000, "0.00") & " KB"
Debug.Print uMsg & vbCr

MsgBox uMsg
```

End Sub

With the three macros on buttons this tedious process may be workable.